# Multiple testing methods

Tags: r, statistics

I want to simulate the effect of different kinds of multiple testing correction such as `Bonferroni`, `Fisher's LSD`, `DUncan`, `Dunn-Sidak Newman-Keuls`, `Tukey`, etc... on `Anova`.

I guess I should simply run a regular `Anova`. And then accept as significant `p.value`s which I calculate by using `p.adjust`. But I'm not getting how this `p.adjust` function works. Could give me some insights about `p.adjust()` ?

when running:

```
> p.adjust(c(0.05,0.05,0.1),"bonferroni")
# [1] 0.15 0.15 0.30
```

Could someone explain as to what does this mean?

Thank you for your answer. I kinda know a bit of all that. But I still don't understand the output of p.adjust. I'd expect that...

> P.adjust(0.08,'bonferroni',n=10)

... would returns 0.008 and not 0.8. n=10 doesn't it mean that I'm doing 10 comparisons. and isn't 0.08 the "original alpha" (I mean the threshold I'd use to reject the NULL hypothesis if I had one simple comparison)

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to read about each multiple testing correction technique, whether it be `False Discovery Rate (FDR)` or `Family-Wise Error Rate (FWER`). (Thanks to @thelatemail for pointing out to expand the abbreviations).

Bonferroni correction controls the `FWER` by setting the significance level `alpha` to `alpha/n` where `n` is the number of hypotheses tested in a typical multiple comparison (here `n=3`).

Let's say you are testing at 5% alpha. Meaning if your p-value is < 0.05, then you reject your NULL. For `n=3`, then, for Bonferroni correction, you could then divide `alpha` by 3 = 0.05/3 ~ 0.0167 and then check if your p-values are < 0.0167.

Equivalently (which is directly evident), instead of checking `pval < alpha/n`, you could take the `n` to the other side `pval * n < alpha`. So that the `alpha` remains the same value. So, your p-values get multiplied by `3` and then would be checked if they are < alpha = 0.05 for example.

Therefore, the output you obtain is the `FWER controlled p-value` and if this is < alpha (5% say), then you would reject the NULL, else you'd accept the NULL hypothesis.

For each tests, there are different procedures to control the false-positives due to multiple testing. Wikipedia might be a good start point to learn about other tests as to how they correct for controlling false-positives.

However, your output of `p.adjust`, gives in general `multiple-testing corrected p-value`. In case of Bonferroni, it is FWER controlled p-value. In case of BH method, it is FDR corrected p-value (or also otherwise called q-value).

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: For those not in the know, FDR = False Discovery Rate

Comment: @thelatemail, Thanks for filling the gaps! Feel free to edit the post to add the info.