# Bonferroni´s correction in a Duncan Test in R

Tags: r, p-value, bonferroni

Im doing the same method that is in the image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24DoO.png), i need to know how can i put the script in R to make the Bonferroni´s correction in the Duncan Test that they mentioned, given "(α´= α/3, α=0.05)". 
I used the following script:

```
  library(agricolae)
  model <- aov(value~ind,data=data.frame)
  comparison <- duncan.test(model, "Ind", main= "comparison")
  duncan.test(model,"ind", console=TRUE)
```

I tried to correct the p-value adding the "alpha" in the duncan.test following one of your answers [Answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927404/multiple-testing-methods) , like this: alpha by 3 = 0.05/3 ~ 0.0167, but it produced an error in the program. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: the docs for that function aren't completely clear to me, but if those are uncorrected pvalues which is what I gather, you can put them through `p.adjust`. the alpha only seems to affect the critical range

Comment: There is a p.adjust function.